# Why is my array not consuming the information I send to it? Swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

Hi I am pretty new to this swift but i know a little, I am trying to insert an image and 2 texts in my array like this:

```
@IBAction func doneEditing(_ sender: Any) {
    insertNewActy()
    print(myCellRows, "Saved")

}


func insertNewActy(){

    addTitles = addTitle.text!
    addLocations = addLocation.text!
    newImages = newImage.image!

    let element = MyCellRows(image: newImages,
                             title: addTitles,
                             location: addLocations)

    myCellRows.insert(element, at: 0)

 }
```

I have 3 variables, one of `UIImage` and 2 of `String`

but nothing happens when I press the `doneEditing` button

Maybe I have put this

```
addTitles = addTitle.text!
addLocations = addLocation.text!
newImages = newImage.image!
```

in the wrong place?

And my array looks like this

```
import UIKit

var myCellRows: [MyCellRows] = []

class ActyViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!


func createMyCellArray() -> [MyCellRows] {

    var myCells: [MyCellRows] = []

    let dog = MyCellRows(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Dog"),
                         title: "Dog",
                         location: "America")
    let cat = MyCellRows(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cat"),
                         title: "Cat",
                         location: "Sweden")
    let rabbit = MyCellRows(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Rabbit"),
                         title: "Rabbit",
                         location: "Germany")
    let tiger = MyCellRows(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Tiger"),
                         title: "Tiger",
                         location: "Africa")

    myCells.append(dog)
    myCells.append(cat)
    myCells.append(rabbit)
    myCells.append(tiger)

    return myCells

}
```

What I am trying to accomplish?

I am trying to add on new cells with 2 custom texts and 1 image from the `users Library on the phone` to my tableview.
The tableView code is correct and works fine.

Thanks for your time. :)

> NOTE: iam using `myTableView.reload()` in my `tableView`class inside `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Do you have to use 'MyCellRows' or could you change the type of it to type String

Comment: @NiallKehoe i would but i want to insert images as well, can i do it this way or do i have to create a String Array and then a Array with images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because the array "myCellRows" contains elements of type "MyCellRows" but in the `func insertNewTitle()`, you are trying to insert an element of type String.
To solve the error, you have to make sure that in `func insertNewTitle()` you are creating an instance of type "MyCellRows" and then appending the element to the "MyCellRows" array.

```
func insertNewTitle(){

let element = MyCellRows(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image"),
                         title: addTitle.text!,
                         location: "Location")

myCellRows.insert(element, at: 0)

}
```

Comment: i tryed this aswell i get no errors but nothing appears when i hit done...

Comment: tableView.reloadData() after updating your data array.

Comment: @PhoneyDeveloper hey where do i imploment this function? in the `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: @PhoneyDeveloper i wrote it in the `viewDidAppear()` but still nothing happens check my question i have edited it a bit

Comment: But insertNewActy() or insertNewTitle() has to happen in response to user action. Whenever that is you have to reloadData() again. After you update your data model you have to reloadData(). Then cellForRowAtIndexPath will be called again for each visible row.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a MyCellRows instance to the `myCellRows.insert(_:at:)` call. If you are trying to insert images and text at the same time, you can just instantiate a new `MyCellRows(image: ???, title: addTitle.text!, location: ???)`.

If you want to insert a row with a title but no image or location, you will have to do a bit of rearchitecting. You could make the `image` and `location` variables on `MyCellRows` optional (`UIImage?` and `String?`), and then pass `image: nil` and `location: nil`, like:

`myCellRows.insert(MyCellRows(image: nil, title: addTitle.text!, location: nil))`

Comment: im trying to `insert` both the image and the title and the location at the same time, sorry if im litle slow but iam new to this heheh, where im i going to `insert` this code? in the `insertNewTitle` function ?

Comment: i did what you said i wrote this      `func` `insertNewTitle(){`
        `myCellRows.insert(MyCellRows(image:` `newImages,` `title:` `addTitles,` `location:` `addLocations),` `at: 0)`
        `newImages` `=` `newImage.image!`
        `addLocations` `=` `addLocation.text!`
        `addTitles` `=` `addTitle.text!`
    `}`

Comment: please look i made this with this 3 variables because i needed to convert them to Type String and Type UIImage now i dont get any error but nothing happens when press DoneEditing button